# Linux64 thread local storage (TLS) data from NASM code

Tags: linux, multithreading, assembly, nasm, x86-64

I try to access thread local storage data from within an ELF64 binary written in NASM-assembler. Segfaults on data access. Here's the code:

```
global _start
global a

section .tdata
    a   dq      59

section .text
    _start:
        mov     rax,[rel a wrt ..gottpoff]   ; As in NASM documentation
        mov     rcx,[fs:rax]                 ; This will crash

        ; Exit process
        mov     rax,231
        syscall
```

The fs:rax access segfaults. The "rel a wrt ..gottpoff] translates to 0xfffffffffffffff8, which looks correct when comparing with GCC output. NASM correctly flags the .tdata section as THREAD_LOCAL.

I don't know what's wrong here ... is there any additional "setup" or whatever I have to do when trying to use TLS data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not show how you assemble and link. My crystal ball says you have forgotten to link against `pthread` (ie. use `-lpthread`). If you don't want to do that, you have to set up `fs` yourself (e.g. by using `arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, .tdata)`) and manage all thread related stuff entirely on your own.

Comment: Thanks, arch_prctl() did the trick, though I tried with an mmap()ed page then accessible at fs:0. Perhaps just reusing the higher end of the thread's stack as arch_prctl() input -as I don't want to waste a whole page- might also be nice, have to try it. And yes, I do the thread-related stuff w/o lpthread/libc.